# how to fix this Access violation reading location error

Tags: c++, pdf-writer

I was using a library called PDF-Writer for C++ (https://github.com/galkahana/PDF-Writer) and I was writing some code like this:

```
void app::saveaspdf()
{
    PDFWriter* pdfWriter = new PDFWriter();
    
    PDFPage* sheet = new PDFPage();
    
    pdfWriter->StartPDF("c:\\a.pdf", ePDFVersion13);
    
    // ...add content to PDF file...
    
    sheet->SetMediaBox(PDFRectangle(0, 0, 595, 842));
    
    sheet->SetRotate(0);
    
    sheet->SetTrimBox(PDFRectangle(0, 0, 595, 842));
    
    sheet->SetCropBox(PDFRectangle(0, 0, 595, 842));
    
    sheet->SetBleedBox(PDFRectangle(0, 0, 595, 842));
    
    sheet->SetArtBox(PDFRectangle(0, 0, 595, 842));
    
    pdfWriter->WritePageAndRelease(sheet);
    
    pdfWriter->EndPDF();
}
```

Then I stumbled on a problem. If I run this, I get an "Access violation reading location" error, and it seems to be `sheet` because on the `mediabox`, `rotation`, `trimbox`, `cropbox`, `bleedbox` and `artbox`'s values seem to be all `0.00000000000`, which is confusing since I defined them on top, as you can see. I also thoroughly checked the Wiki on the GitHub page and it said:

https://github.com/galkahana/PDF-Writer/wiki/Creating-PDF-Pages

> Note that a PDF Page has more boxes definition than just a Media Box.
> PDF defines a Crop Box, a Bleed Box, A Trim Box and an Art Box. you can set these boxes up by using `SetCropBox`, `SetBleedBox`, `SetTrimBox` and `SetArtBox` respectively.

And only that after the example code, so I don't know what I did wrong here. So, how do I solve these errors?

Comment: Which line of code exactly is raising the AV error? Have you run the code through your compiler's debugger yet?

Comment: it seems to be the last 2 lines

Comment: That implies the `sheet` is corrupted. Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger to watch what happens to the `sheet` on every statement?

Comment: may i ask how to (i am on visual studio)

Comment: now that i try to run it without the sheet part it still has the same problem on the last line